# What is the function in C returns the current directory?

Tags: c, unix

What is the function in C returns the current directory? (Among UNIX)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The POSIX standard is `getcwd()`, which stands for "get current working directory".

Answer (score 6):

`getcwd`. On my box:

```
GETCWD(3)                  Linux Programmer's Manual                 GETCWD(3)

NAME
       getcwd, getwd, get_current_dir_name - Get current working directory

SYNOPSIS
       #include 

       char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size);

       char *getwd(char *buf);

       char *get_current_dir_name(void);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, this will help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main ()
{
printf("you are currently in: %s", get_current_dir_name());
}
```

output:

```
/home/me/Desktop/tmp
```

Comment: According to `man getcwd`, `get_current_dir_name()` malloc's a block of memory large enough to hold the absolute path. You must free the pointer returned by it after you use it.